# Can't load image from raw to imageview

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to load image using setImageResource, from raw folder to imageview, But I get Expected resource of type drawable error.

I'm using android studio, Before that when I was using Eclipse everything was fine.
I don't want to use drawable folder.

[image: Error]

raw folder:

[image: raw folder in my project]

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use drawable folder ?

Comment: because drawable scaled down images depend of device

Comment: If you only add 1 image to 1 type of drawable, you won't get autoscale.  But you can put an image file in raw, you're just going to have to open it using BitmapFactory and then pass the bitmap to the imageview.

Comment: In that case you can create a `drawable-nodpi` folder and put your image there and it won't be scaled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to load image using setImageResource, from raw folder to imageview, But I get Expected resource of type drawable error.

Using a raw resource for `setImageResource()` is not documented behavior.

> Before that when I was using Eclipse everything was fine

Not really. While your code runs, it might not on all past, present, and future versions of Android. This is why there is a compiler warning.

> because drawable scaled down images depend of device

Use `drawable-nodpi` for drawables that should not be scaled based upon screen density. That is usually not a good idea, but perhaps you have a reason for it.

A safer approach for using a raw resource would be to use `openRawResource()` on `Resources` to get an `InputStream`, then use `BitmapFactory` to read in the bitmap.

You are welcome to suppress the warning with `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")`, but do not complain when your app stops working.

Answer (score 5):

You can try it

```
   InputStream imageStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.name);
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
   imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```