# get raw file data from url and display in ImageView

Tags: android

I would like to display an image from the URL that is providing me raw data for the image(png or JPG).

I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576152/raw-data-to-jpeg-format-java) but not much useful.

Here is my image [link](https://video.freedomrobotics.ai/AF9111FB06CD795D636B8E2AA/D40A19737B5CFE9122E55BE5AC6/%252Fusb_cam%252Fimage_raw?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Date=20200902T153304Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEJb%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMiJIMEYCIQDY6b3y%2BDpagqB7FXVfqJMfT1ZaGISXNbxwdjHKeZzSewIhAJp%2BOHu2GIuREzoNAL28CYmzlWHExDX0j5H927eO9bbPKvsBCI%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEQARoMNjQ5NzQ2NjAwODc1Igx3SJacAYY3xajfPQcqzwGpgttiFT9EyJHxW1APqS54ElQVJVQXsppbW9tjSxq%2F7BfT1OAjQVUwplmOmaXX40lUMNzNP8zXixTFnZw7UUndKMrQ35xFjMMdymTUHpqLHhGjvDtbjDWoxOUfWrGGJWPiY3f7c05KEMvRLljTwUEImraBa1JzlbEwjsoZfe2ZPEt6ns9aDZq8wBxy3D3JbtgIB3aR9wEfOYe5Ynw2Sct3vKAYmAEALKpxcl5t7M4%2BVQjZTi5Y1FZW2qk5MvDFRtGP05vx9gVs62nXHScj53wwyNO%2B%2BgU63wF8ScOxmdeWSPS8u6Hj4ZG3t4Srl6nJRdsAygpHXwrqGsKnpVyWU9uij3Zxvn27Pmz5k%2BCSkENz%2BG%2B2Yh7EZthvlRO%2FpjaD75P1oBBlfYTWyxDoSbNSU%2FGiDhSRzUTv8trF06DIB1%2BQp1pnZVAJroQt0Gol0dnnAgb2rwz8C3v%2FZ19RdcDhx8u0rS1a0TnGFTRlHr7P%2BtRsWYh9VRD03ssaa1Zw4P%2BMfmMHO4bn8srNUd5tbnExjom4JpwwMlibo%2FtmAIg2JKP0GwB%2FE%2B%2FjRNfLjHSqtg3cQAeIGx8%2FouCQ&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAZOR7KKOVQ6MGOHNU%2F20200902%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=56f2f17468867839e13cb2691e9513e62031662151fb69a0126304167c69a8e5)

I am processing the raw data but could not see the image. I am not sure how do I check that I got the right raw data.

here is my effort

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        byte[] bytes;
        Bitmap picture = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

//            final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
//
//            Request request = new Request.Builder()
//                    .url(urls[0])
//                    .build();
//
//            Response response = null;
//
//            try {
//                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
//            } catch (IOException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
//            assert response != null;
//            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
//                try {
//                    assert response.body() != null;
//                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//                    IOUtils.copy(response.body().byteStream(), baos);
//                    bytes = baos.toByteArray();
//                    picture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.body().byteStream());
//                } catch (Exception e) {
//                    Log.e("Error", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
//                    e.printStackTrace();
//                }
//
//            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            try {
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                byte[] chunk = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead;
                InputStream stream = url.openStream();

                while ((bytesRead = stream.read(chunk)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }

            bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            if (bytes != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                cameraView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
//            cameraView.setImageBitmap(picture);

        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with raw data for an image? Aren't you just downloading an image file like a .jpg or .png?

Comment: No, Data coming in raw format from the url so I need to convert that into the image

Comment: Your code looks ok for downloading image files. If you are in doubt receiving the right bytes then save them to file and check if an image viewer can fidplay it.

Comment: Repeat: what do you mean with raw format? And you are trying to convert the bytes to a bitmap. Did you check if bimap==null?

Comment: @blackapps here the link I am getting the data from https://pastebin.com/tifdC2K3

Comment: Quite confusing post. It looks if you are downloading a .raw file. And not the raw data of for instance a .jpg file.

Comment: It expires every 6 seconds so I can't really put in the question.

Comment: ?? But what should i see in that pastebin? Dont understand a word. You better post the used url here. And what is expiring?

Comment: That is the link where I am getting that data from

Comment: Please react: `It looks if you are downloading a .raw file. And not the raw data of for instance a .jpg file. `

Comment: My god... Tell better what you mean by raw data. I asked you several times and you seem not able to tell what it is that you try to download.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220872/discussion-between-arpit-patel-and-blackapps).

Comment: @blackapps Can you join the discussion? So I can explain to you better.

Comment: No. I will not. Just give a to the point answer. Cant be that difficult.

Comment: in the simple term, I would like to display an image using the URL link but the link contains the jpg data in that URL.

Comment: You are trying to download a .jpg file. Ok. Why all that fuss? Pretty normal then it should work. But you did not tell if bitmap became null although i asked you. If bitmap becomes null then tell the resolution in pixels of that image.

Comment: It's not the jpg file but I would like to save as a jpg file.

Comment: @ArpitPatel how can I create a row link with no expiration date

Answer (score 1):

The location of your problem/s in your workflow seems ill-determined.
You should first identify this.
(Plus, you did not specify if you are bound to a specific programming language).

For this sake, I suggest you:

1. Start using a raw image file that you know is correct, and test its processing.
   There are quite a few [raw image formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format).
   Judging from the tag `android`, I guess the following can help:

   To capture a raw iamge into a file: [How to capture raw image from android camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777953/how-to-capture-raw-image-from-android-camera)

   To display in ImageView: [Can't load image from raw to imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548475/cant-load-image-from-raw-to-imageview)

   https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14046/how-can-i-convert-an-image-from-raw-data-in-android-without-any-munging

   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat

   https://www.androidcentral.com/raw-images-and-android-everything-you-need-know
2. Try getting a raw image from an URL that you can manage.
3. Apply this to the actual target URL.

This way you will know where your problem resides.
Without more info it is hard to "debug" your problem.

You can also inspect code in [FOSS projects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format#Free_and_open_source_software).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you give me an example that retrieves raw data and display as an image in Android?

Comment: I checked all the references but couldn't see the proper way to display the raw image in android

Comment: @ArpitPatel - As mentioned, your task can be split into "subtasks". I was suggesting you first take some additional time to clarify where your problem resides, instead of asking for a complete code for the whole process. This is a way to help others help you, and it increases chances that you get your problem solved..

Comment: I implemented the code but I am not getting any errors So I am just trying to identify the errors. Or what is wrong with my code if I am making any mistakes.

Comment: @ArpitPatel - As for showing in ImageView, please see updated answer.
Again, please help narrowing down the problem.

Comment: If you guys need any more information please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the following questions:

```
Using URL to get bytes to load images
```

I wrote down what I can with reference to

```
class DownLoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
         super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
         imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

     }

     @Override
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
         try {
             OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
             Request request = new Request.Builder().url(strings[0]).build();
             Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
             if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                 InputStream inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                 return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
             }
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
     }
 }
```

This is the URL I use

> https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/440px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png
>
> https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Cat03.jpg

I can test it. I hope it can help you

Comment: Can you upload in java ?

Comment: update to java ,The repeated creation of okhttp requests needs to be processed by yourself @Arpit Patel

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library named Picasso and do the following:

```
String url = get url from the Async Function and convert it to String
/*if you url has no image format, you could do something like this con convert the uri into a Bitmap*/


public Bitmap getCorrectlyOrientedImage(Context context, Uri uri, int maxWidth)throws IOException {

InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
onlyBoundsOptions.inDither = true;//optional
onlyBoundsOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//optional
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, onlyBoundsOptions);
try {
      input.close();

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
 }

/*trying to get the right orientation*/
if ((onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth == -1) || (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight == -1)) {
            return null;
        }

int originalSize = Math.max(onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight, onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth);

double ratio = (originalSize > maxWidth) ? (originalSize / maxWidth) : 1.0;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        int rotationInDegrees = exifToDegrees(orientation);
        if (orientation != 0) matrix.preRotate(rotationInDegrees);

        int bmpWidth = 0;
        try {
            assert bitmap != null;
            bmpWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Bitmap adjustedBitmap = bitmap;
if (bmpWidth > 0)
   adjustedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

return adjustedBitmap;
}

/*Then you has the image in Bitmap, you can use the solution below or if Picasso doesn't allows you to put Bitmap you can pass it directly to the ImageView as a Bitmap.*/

ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);

/*Then use Picasso to draw the image into the ImageView*/
Picasso.with(context).load(url).fit().into(imageView );
```

This is the dependency for `build.gradle`, not sure if is the last version but you could try.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Kind regards!

Comment: This URL doesn't provide jpg or png. I can not use URL directly I need to do processing to convert data to JPG or png.

Comment: How you are storing the image? I think with Picasso, no matter how is the url, it will just find the url and try to put whatever is there into the ImageView, did you already try?

Comment: I am using a third party URL to display the image so I am not sure how they store the data.

Comment: I updated my answer, so can convert the uri into a Bitmap and then assign it to the ImageView, hope it match to your needs.

Comment: I tried to download data as a bitmap but its not working you can see on my question.

Comment: Yes, I saw your question, but the solution is not the same

Comment: Are you able to see the image when debugging the app as a Bitmap already converted?